# Steps to succesfully persistent iSCSI LUN using Open-iSCSI on Ubuntu Server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iscsi, network-attached-storage, open-iscsi

Using Ubuntu Linux Server 22.04 minimal edition without GUI, I need some help in mounting the iSCSI LUN using Open-iSCSI so it is mapped to /dev/sdb with the below command:

Could you please let me know if I missed any steps on the following:

Edit the file **/etc/iscsi/initiatorname.iscsi** into:

```
InitiatorName=iqn.2023-02.com.domain.repo01:repo01.initiator01
```

and then continue with:

```
sudo systemctl restart iscsid open-iscsi
sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t sendtargets -p 192.168.1.111 (this is the IP address of my NAS target).
sudo iscsiadm -m node -o show 
sudo iscsiadm -m node –login
sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p 192.168.1.111
```

Edit the **/etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf** file and set the value into:

```
node.startup = automatic
```

and then reboot the VM.

However, when I check with the below command after multiple reboot no **/dev/sdb** mounted

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

If you could provide me with any assistance, I would greatly appreciate it.